# To customize my custom local created scopes in search dialog

Tags: phpstorm

In PhpStorm 2019.2.3 I use search in the project with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+F</kbd> key and:

1. Is a way to set search dialog opened with one of my custom scopes by some hotkey?
2. Is listing of scopes configurable? As my custom created scopes appears at the end of the scopes listing and actually I do not use my default scopes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Alt+S` for changing to the scope view, no way to change scopes order, unfortunately.

A feature request for disabling the predefined ones: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-175719